# Deduce if the series converges absolutely or conditionally.

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{}^\ (-1)^k \frac{(3^k)(k!)^2}{(2k)!}$$

I start by using the absolute convergence test. This eliminates the -1: |1|^k = 1

Then I use the ratio test.

$$\left|\frac{3^{k+1} (k+1)!^2}{(2(k+1))!}\frac{(2k)!}{3^k(k!)^2}\right|$$

Then you simplify and get

$$\frac{3(k+1!)^2(2k)!}{(2(k+1))!(k!)^2}.$$

Then after simplifying further you get

$$\frac{3(k+1)^2}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}.$$

Factor and get

$$\frac{3(k+1)}{2(2k+1)}$$

How does one from this point get a exact value? This is where I am lost.

Comment: You don't need an exact value, the limit suffices. ($\limsup$ actually suffices, but the quotients converge here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ratio test, the idea is that you take the limit of the ratio of the terms as the index goes to infinity:
$$L = \lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|$$
Then the series diverges if $L>1$ and converges if $L<1$. Here you have simplified $\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|$ but have yet to take the limit as $k\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use the ratio test. The ratio test for a sum $\{s_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n} \right|<1$$ So take the limit in the last line you have to see if your sum is convergent.

Comment: In fact, to fully answer the OPs question, it is Absolute Convergent...